# Xstream return a string instead of the object (unmarshal)

Tags: java, unmarshalling, xstream

Xml:

```
<FooBar>
    <foo name="FooName">
        <bar .../>
        <bar .../>
    </foo>
</FooBar>
```

Java :

```
class FooBar {
    private Foo foo;
}
```

What I looking for is a way to not store `Foo` object in `FooBar` but instead add `Foo` object in a static Map and store only the attribute name (FooName) in class `FooBar`.

In other words I want to parse `foo` only if it's needed (unknown name) and store the name in `FooBar`.

Something like this :

FooBar.java

```
class FooBar {
    @XStreamConverter(FooConverter.class)
    private String foo;
}
```

FooConverter.java

```
public class FooConverter extends ReflectionConverter {

    public FooConverter(Mapper mapper, ReflectionProvider reflectionProvider) {
        super(mapper, reflectionProvider);
    }

    @Override
    public void marshal(Object o, HierarchicalStreamWriter writer, MarshallingContext mc) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }

    @Override
    public Object unmarshal(HierarchicalStreamReader reader, UnmarshallingContext uc) {
        String name = reader.getAttribute("name");
        Foo foo = FOOMAP.get(name);

        if (foo != null) {
            return name;
        }
        foo = (Foo) super.unmarshal(reader, uc);
        FOOMAP.put(name, foo);

        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canConvert(Class type) {
        return type == Foo.class || type == String.class;
    }

}
```

The purpose is to only parse one time `foo` tag if we already know it (same name attribute) and be able to do a kind of include with `<foo name="FooName" />`, as "FooName" is already known.

Answer (score 0):

`ReflectionConverter` have a function `doUnmarshal` and first arguments is an Object.

```
@Override
public Object unmarshal(HierarchicalStreamReader reader, UnmarshallingContext uc) {
    String name = reader.getAttribute("name");
    Foo foo = FOOMAP.get(name);

    if (foo != null) {
        return name;
    }

    foo = (Foo) super.doUnmarshal(new Foo(), reader, uc);
    if(foo.getSomething() != null) // check if foo is not empty
        FOOMAP.put(name, foo);

    return name;
}

@Override
public boolean canConvert(Class type) {
    return type.equals(String.class);
}
```

It's not nice but it works.